Not updatable query access (updating with count)
I'm trying to update a table with users (salesmen) with their assigned cases. All salesmen start with a base number, eg. 700 cases. Using a query over the table of cases I assigned already a few cases to them.
SalesMen



idSalesMen
SalesMenName
MaxCases




1
John Doe
700


2
Jane Doe
700



In MS Access I wrote this query [Cuenta  Asignados P1] as follows to get the total number of cases assigned to a salesman:
SELECT Cases.SalesMenId, Count(Cases.Id) AS CountOfId
FROM Cases
GROUP BY Cases.SalesMenId
HAVING (((Cases.SalesMenId)<>IsNull([SalesMenId])));

I saved that query and I wanna use it to update the SalesMen table MaxCases column.
This is the update query I'm attempting to work out.
UPDATE SalesMen AS A INNER JOIN [Cuenta  Asignados P1] 
ON A.SalesMenId= [Cuenta  Asignados P1].SalesMenId 
SET A.MaxCases = A.MaxCases - [Cuenta  Asignados P1].[CountOfId];

However, that doesn't work because (I'm translating) "The Operation Must Use An Updateable Query".

See: Why is my query not updateable?

Consider domain aggregates like DCount to update data:
UPDATE SalesMen s
SET s.MaxCases = s.MaxCases - DCount("*","Cases", "SalesMenId=" & s.SalesMenId)

